# Will a not SSL http request affect my website's security?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Recently installed a SSL Certificate on my webserver for our new website. Now I'm building the website and want to use ogp.me, but they only offer a non SSL http link.

Will this affect the security of my website?

Our website does not have any 'secrets' or sensitive information, only a contact form.

Comment: I'm not sure in what context they only offer a http link...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Code: '<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">'. I was wondering if this affects the security on the website because I have SSL enabled).

I see the comment disables http:// So the link ogp.me is http:// and not https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<html prefix="og: ogp.me/ns#">` is your only http reference, then no, that link will *not* affect your security.

In fact, that link is really an Open Graph namespace declaration, that is it's just the *name of a namespace*, not an URL at all even if it looks exactly like one.